# How to prevent covering a ScrollView embedded in ZStack when scrolling to the bottom of the ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have HStack and ScrollView in ZStack, how can I prevent the HStack from covering the bottom of ScrollView? I think there is a modifier to fix this issue, but I can’t remember it.

```
struct Messages: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack() {
                    MessagesList()
                }
            }
            MessageInput()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the `ZStack` and declare the view that sticks to the bottom using the `.safeAreaInset` modifier, e.g.:

```swift
ScrollView {
  // etc.
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
  MessageInput()
}
```

More information on [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-inset-the-safe-area-with-custom-content) and [Apple’s developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-99dyd)